# Mono compatibility with bool Type.op_Equality (Type, Type)

Tags: mono

I am considering changing from VS2010 to Mono and as such I ran my assemblies through MoMA to see how much difficulties I may have with the transition. On the generated report I found that I continually get this error:

```
bool Type.op_Equality (Type, Type)  Implement it properly once 4.0 impl details are known.
```

I checked the class status pages and have seen that bool Type.op_Equality is listed as being a TODO in both 4.5 and 4.0 in mscorlib.dll (system namespace) with it awaiting impl details. which brings me to my question:

**Does anyone know if/when implementation details will be available? Or if I ignore this TODO, will my code still work?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard about any bugs related to Mono's implementation of Type.op_Equality (which doesn't mean there aren't any of course).

The only way to actually know if your code will work is to try it out on mono. MoMA is just a guide, not an oracle, and as such it lists *potential* issues (with a varying degree of seriousness).

For any particular code in Mono it is also possible to check the source code to see if the message you get in MoMA affects you or not.

For instance: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/Type.cs#L482.